# Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: r, error-handling, r-s4

I'm trying to make a formula and I got the error:

> $ operator not defined for this S4 class with R.

First of all, what is a S4 class? What am I doing wrong?

Following the code:

```
as.formula("ctree(d$sex ~ d$ahe , data = d)")
```

If you want to reproduce it, the dataset (CSV file) `d` is [available here](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/blob/master/csv/Ecdat/CPSch3.csv).

Comment: Generally, when there's a `data` argument, you shouldn't *also* use `$`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are giving `as.formula` the wrong input here. Only `d$sex ~ d$ahe` should be a formula, so:

```
ctree(as.formula("d$sex ~ d$ahe"))
```

Or:

```
ctree(as.formula("sex ~ ahe"), data = d)
```

Comment: The second option is prefered and usually safer.

Comment: This answer doesn't tell about `First of all, what is a S4 class?`

Comment: @AbelCallejo That's because the S4 object has nothing to do with `What am I doing wrong here?`. It's just the error that OP got from misapplying the code, and it could have been a completely different error had OP used a different function than `ctree`.

Comment: ... or even simpler `ctree(sex ~ ahe, data = d)`?

Comment: @Gregor-reinstateMonica That could also work, but OP specifically used a string and `as.formula`. (This setup has the unique advantage that you can make strings a priori and then supply them to a function that takes formulas, whereas your answer is hard-coded.)