# R: Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class when using RadAR package

Tags: r, data-visualization, r-s4

I am trying to visualize features that were extracted from a dataset of CT-scans using radiomics. I extracted features using the Pyradiomics library, and now I have a few `.csv` files.

I found [this](https://github.com/cgplab/RadAR) R Library which can read a dataset and generate images for it. Reading the dataset works according to plan using the `input = import_pyradiomics(dir = "/path/to/datadir")` command, but when I try to visualize it using for instance `plot_correlation_matrix(rdr = input, view_as = "heatmap")`, one of the visualization functions, I get the following error:

`Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

I read about S3 and S4 classes, and I think that [[line 160](https://github.com/cgplab/RadAR/blob/master/R/visualization_functions.R)] in the library is where this error occurs first as it attempts to call this '$' operator. I am currently using R version 4.0.2. It seems to me like this issue is caused by this R library relying on an older version of R, but it is relatively up to date. What can I do to resolve this issue? Do I have to go in and manually change the code in the library? Or is there an easier fix, such as casting the S4 class to an S3 class? I feel like I'm missing an easy solution because I'm not familiar with R.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737628/error-operator-not-defined-for-this-s4-class), but it doesn't answer my specific question. Answers on other questions regarding this topic also do not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the developer of RadAR, thank you for your interest in our package. The issue was probably related to the use of a different version of the SummarizedExperiment R package. The bug has now been fixed. You can re-install the new version of RadAR from https://github.com/cgplab/RadAR.
For any questions related to RadAR, please refer to the "issues" section of the RadAR github page.